# Using Temporary files in Django Celery Results

Tags: python, django, export, celery, temporary-files

I'm using a celery task to generate PDF and Excel exports for user data. These tasks build the temporary files. Here's the problem. I'm using [NamedTemporaryFile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) objects, which automatically delete themselves when the file is closed. Since they're closed at the end of the task, they simply disappear immediately.

I can get it working if I set the delete property to false:

```
NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
```

But this has the problem of leaving a bunch of temp files on the system, which I don't want.

I could always create a cleanup task, but I was hoping there might be a better pattern out there...

Thanks!

Comment: When do you want these files to be deleted?

Comment: What do you do with the files after you generate them?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [StringIO/CStringIO](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html) class instead of NamedTemporaryFile to capture the data from the Excel/PDF file and return its value. StringIO class behaves the same way a normal file would.